# Is O_LARGEFILE needed just to write a large file?

Tags: c, large-files, file-descriptor, posix-api, large-file-support

Is the `O_LARGEFILE` flag needed if all that I want to do is write a large file (`O_WRONLY`) or append to a large file (`O_APPEND | O_WRONLY`)?

From a thread that I read titled "[Cannot write >2gb index file](http://www.mail-archive.com/clucene-developers@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00069.html)" on the CLucene-dev mailing list, it appears that `O_LARGEFILE` might be needed to write large files, but participants in that discussion are using `O_RDWR`, not `O_WRONLY`, so I am not sure.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`O_LARGEFILE` should never be used directly by applications. It's to be used internally by the 64-bit-offset-compatible version of `open` in libc when it makes the syscall to the kernel (Linux, or possibly another kernel with this 64-bit-offset-mode-is-a-second-class-citizen nonsense). Just make sure to always include `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` in your `CFLAGS` and you'll never have to worry about anything.

Comment: Do you have any source for that O_LARGEFILE should not be used?

Comment: The best source is the fact that grepping POSIX for it turns up zero results.

Comment: So you mean, O_LARGEFILE is something like a cap ? It must be some reason why this flag exists.

Comment: On 32-bit systems, the version of `open` used with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` passes `O_LARGEFILE` to the kernel transparently. The version used with 32-bit `off_t` does not. This in turn determines "the offset maximum established in the open file description", in the language of POSIX, which causes a number of functions to report errors when they would result in a file offset that can't be represented in the 32-bit `off_t`. The maximum is associated with the open file description rather than the process since open file descriptions can be shared between processes.

Comment: In any case, there's absolutely no reason to poke at `O_LARGEFILE` yourself. If you're using 64-bit `off_t` on a 32-bit system, it will be set automatically for you, and otherwise (on 64-bit systems, or on 32-bit systems with 32-bit `off_t`), it should not be set.

Comment: Does POSIX mention `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS`? Can you link to it?

Comment: No, it's a glibc thing. Sane systems always use 64-bit offsets. POSIX allows multiple environments and the getconf command can tell you the CFLAGS for a particular one.

Answer (score 12):

IIRC if you do

```
#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
```

before all other includes you do not need to pass this flag.

[additionally see](http://www.suse.de/~aj/linux_lfs.html)

Comment: `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` is not needed, only `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS`.