# Large file support

Tags: linux

Could someone please explain, what exactly this `O_LARGEFILE` option does to support opening of large files. 
And can there be any side effects of compiling with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` flag. In other words, when compiled with this option do we have to make sure something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is O_LARGEFILE needed just to write a large file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888425/is-o-largefile-needed-just-to-write-a-large-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  _FILE_OFFSET_BITS in preference to O_LARGEFILE.   These are used on 32 bit systems to allow opening files so large that they exceed the range of a 32bit file pointer.

No, you don't have to do anything special.  If you are on 64bit Linux it makes no difference anyway.

Answer (score 1):

From `man 2 open`:

```
   O_LARGEFILE
          (LFS)  Allow  files  whose  sizes  cannot  be  represented  in  an  off_t (but can be represented in an off64_t) to be opened.  The _LARGE‐
          FILE64_SOURCE macro must be defined in order to obtain this definition.  Setting the _FILE_OFFSET_BITS feature test  macro  to  64  (rather
          than   using  O_LARGEFILE)  is  the  preferred  method  of  obtaining  method  of  accessing  large  files  on  32-bit  systems  (see  fea‐
          ture_test_macros(7)).
```

Edit: (ie. RTM :P)

Comment: The manpage usually doesn't point out the reason directly, so sometimes people like OP and me may want some confirmation from others, ensuring that we get it right.