# open larger file with "gnu open" on Windows 64bits in C

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit

I'm using the function

```
int open (const char *filename, int flags[, mode_t mode])
```

in my code to open files.

```
    file->fd = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_BINARY);
    if (file->fd == -1) {
        perror("cannot open file");
        return -1;
    }
```

My code is running well on GNU/linux (64bit) but on Windows (64bit) I can't open file larger than 4Go.
I would understand I have this kind of problem on 32bit systems, but I do not understand why it is the case on Windows 64bit.
I've read [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-and-Closing-Files.html) and there is the function open64. However this function is dedicated to 32bit systems which is not my case (Don't care about 32bits systems).

I don't think this topic is a doublon because all the topics I've read explain how to use the macros `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` or `-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1`, but again it is for 32bit system.
I've also [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790822/reading-a-large-file-using-c-greater-than-4gb-using-read-function-causing-pro) that there's a flag: O_LARGEFILE to do it. But apparently it is a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888425/is-o-largefile-needed-just-to-write-a-large-file) as it should be done automatically.

I'm stuck and I do not want to change all my code to use `fopen`, so if anyone has a solution for opening large file with open in Windows it could be great.

Comment: On Windows, are you using Cygwin or similar POSIX compatibility layer? If you do, is it a 64-bit install of it?

Comment: I'm not the one compiling the software on Windows but I believe it is done with mingw 64bits.

Comment: MinGW is nothing more than the GCC compiler ported to Windows, it does not have a POSIX compatibility layer (and [`open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) is a POSIX function, it's not standard in Windows). You should probably get more information from the person attempting to build your application on Windows.

Comment: The software is compiling very well. And it is running too.

Comment: By the way. On linux I'm using gcc and it works well. The same on OS X.
Only Windows gives this issue.

Comment: Both Linux and macOS are POSIX platforms, which have a native `open` function. Windows does *not* have a native `open` function. Windows do have the somewhat compatible [`_open`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-wopen) function, and there are of course POSIX compatibility systems like [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). Without knowing what is used on the Windows system, there's no way of answering this, it's to broad. ***You*** need to get more information from the person building this on Windows, and edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Your explanation is great. Thank you. I've read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z.aspx I think that I could use `_wopen` in windows case.

Comment: `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` etc are specific to glibc. No Windows environment uses glibc.

Comment: Note that even though the Windows *OS* is 64-bit, a lot of programs (and development environments) are still 32-bit because of inertia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have found a solution.
Indeed Windows does not have POSIX compatibility and this is the problem (as mentionned by @Some programmer dude.
But the open function does the job. The problem comes from lseek.
I need to do something like that:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <io.h>
#endif
...
#ifdef WIN32
#define lseek64 _lseeki64
#else
#define lseek64 lseek
#endif
```

Then, the type of lseek use to be `off_t`. But this type is also POSIX standard. So, the last thing I did is to replace all the `off_t` by `int64_t`.

It is now working very well.