# How can I write/create a file larger than 2GB by using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, large-files

I tried to use write() function to write a large piece of memory into a file (more than 2GB) but never succeed. Can somebody be nice and tell me what to do?

Comment: What file system and what operating system are we talking about?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: How did you try to write it? A code snippet would be nice.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560238/how-to-create-a-file-of-size-more-than-2gb-in-linux-unix/45574824#45574824

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Linux :)

[https://users.suse.com/~aj/linux_lfs.html](https://users.suse.com/%7Eaj/linux_lfs.html)

- Define `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` to 64. (`gcc -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`)
- Define `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` and `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE`.
- Use the `O_LARGEFILE` flag with `open()` to operate on large file

Also some information there:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-Streams.html#index-fopen64-931

These days the file systems you have on your system will support large file out of the box.

Comment: Only step 1 is necessary or beneficial. 2-4 are bogus/outdated/harmful to portability.

Comment: Hey I tried that. In fact by using fopen64 I can create a file with maximum sizeo of 4GB now. But I need bigger. Anyway, thx for you advice.

Answer (score 3):

Add `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` to your compiler command line (aka `CFLAGS`) and it will work. This is not necessary on any 64-bit system and it's also unnecessary on some (but not all) 32-bit systems these days.

Avoid advice to go writing `O_LARGEFILE` or `open64` etc. all over your source. This is non-portable and, quite simply, ugly.

**Edit:** Actually, I think we've all misread your issue. If you're on a 32-bit system, the largest possible single object in memory is 2GB-1byte (i.e. `SSIZE_MAX`). Per POSIX, the behavior of `write` for size arguments that cannot fit in `ssize_t` is not defined; this is because `write` returns type `ssize_t` and could not represent the number of bytes written if it were larger. Perhaps more importantly, it's dangerous for an implementation to allow objects so large that their size does not fit in `ptrdiff_t`, since that would create a situation where pointer arithmetic could invoke integer overflow and thus undefined behavior. You may have been able to create such a large object with `mmap` (I would consider this a bug in your system's kernel or libc), but it's a very bad idea and will lead to all sorts of bugs. If you need single objects larger than 2GB, you really need to run on a 64-bit machine to have it be safe and bug-free.

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon the operating system, the processor, the file system. On Linux/x86-64 systems (with ext3 file systems) it is trivial to do. Just use the usual library functions (in C++ `std::ofstream`, in C `<stdio.h>`, `fopen` && `fprintf` etc.) or the underlying system calls (open, write).